# Converting intel RealSense D415 bag file to PCD

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bag-to-pcd, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert a bag file generated from intel RealSense D415 to PCD (or any point cloud) that I can use and manipulate on CloudCompare. I'm using the command:

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <input_file.bag> <topic> <output_directory>
```

It's actually executed but when I go to the output directory it's actually empty.

I'm using the bash shell on windows 10, and ROS Kinetic Desktop-Full Install.

BTW: I've used `rosbag info file.bag` to know the topics available in the bag file, and the output is below:

```
version:      2.0
duration:     10.3s
start:        Jan 01 1970 02:00:00.00 (0.00)
end:          Jan 01 1970 02:00:10.35 (10.35)
size:         416.7 MB
messages:     2328
compression:  lz4 [376/376 chunks; 59.66%]
uncompressed: 698.1 MB @ 67.5 MB/s
compressed:   416.5 MB @ 40.2 MB/s (59.66%)
types:        diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue  [cf57fdc6617a881a88c16e768132149c]
              geometry_msgs/Transform   [ac9eff44abf714214112b05d54a3cf9b]
              realsense_msgs/StreamInfo [311d7e24eac31bb87271d041bf70ff7d]
              sensor_msgs/CameraInfo    [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
              sensor_msgs/Image         [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
              std_msgs/Float32          [73fcbf46b49191e672908e50842a83d4]
              std_msgs/String           [992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1]
              std_msgs/UInt32           [304a39449588c7f8ce2df6e8001c5fce]
topics:       /device_0/info                                                      8 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/data                137 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/image/metadata           685 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info                                     1 msg     : realsense_msgs/StreamInfo
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/info/camera_info                 1 msg     : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo
              /device_0/sensor_0/Depth_0/tf/0                                     1 msg     : geometry_msgs/Transform
              /device_0/sensor_0/Infrared_1/image/data                       97 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
              /device_0/sensor_0/Infrared_1/image/metadata                485 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue
              /device_0/sensor_0/Infrared_1/info                                  1 msg     : realsense_msgs/StreamInfo
              /device_0/sensor_0/Infrared_1/info/camera_info                    1 msg     : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo
              /device_0/sensor_0/Infrared_1/tf/0                                  1 msg     : geometry_msgs/Transform
              /device_0/sensor_0/info                                             1 msg     : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Asic Temperature/description              1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Asic Temperature/value                    1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth Units/description                   1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth Units/value                         1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter Enabled/description               1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter Enabled/value                     1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable Auto Exposure/description          1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable Auto Exposure/value                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable Auto White Balance/description     1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable Auto White Balance/value           1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Error Polling Enabled/description         1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Error Polling Enabled/value               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames Queue Size/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames Queue Size/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/description                          1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/value                                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser Power/description                   1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser Power/value                         1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Output Trigger Enabled/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Output Trigger Enabled/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Projector Temperature/description         1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Projector Temperature/value               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo Baseline/description               1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo Baseline/value                     1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual Preset/description                 1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual Preset/value                       1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data                             141 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/metadata                    705 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info                                     1 msg     : realsense_msgs/StreamInfo
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info/camera_info                         1 msg     : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/tf/0                                     1 msg     : geometry_msgs/Transform
              /device_0/sensor_1/info                                             1 msg     : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto Exposure Priority/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto Exposure Priority/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight Compensation/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight Compensation/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/description                    1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/value                          1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto Exposure/description          1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto Exposure/value                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto White Balance/description     1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto White Balance/value           1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames Queue Size/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames Queue Size/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/description                          1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/value                                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/description                         1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/value                               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/description                           1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/value                                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Power Line Frequency/description          1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Power Line Frequency/value                1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/description                    1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/value                          1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/description                     1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/value                           1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/White Balance/description                 1 msg     : std_msgs/String
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/White Balance/value                       1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32
              /file_version
```

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301535/converting-intel-realsense-d415-bag-file-to-pcd/) by [gamesmechanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37151/gamesmechanic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-25**:
Can you give us some more information so we can help you. The actual rosrun command you're using and the output of rosbag info

**Comment by [gamesmechanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37151/gamesmechanic/) on 2018-08-26**:
Thanks PeteBlackerThe3rd for your reply, I'm using Ubuntu 16 on windows 10, and I've edited the question to include the output of rosbag info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [pcl_ros bag_to_pcd](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#bag_to_pcd) you're using converts all the points cloud messages in a bad file into pcd files. The problem is the bag file you're using doesn't contain any point cloud messages hence why no pcd files are being created.

The bag file does contain depth images, RBG images and infrared images as well as their associated camera_info messages. This is enough to generate the point cloud messages using the [depth_image_proc nodele](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc#depth_image_proc.2BAC8-point_cloud_xyzrgb)t though. You'll have to start this nodelet with the right topics setup and then play the bag file to generate the point cloud messages you need.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gamesmechanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/37151/gamesmechanic/) on 2018-08-26**:
Thanks PeteBlackerThe3rd, I'll give it a try and get back with the results to help others who might have the same problem. thanks again:-)